# Search on product when either area or customer is assigned and subsequently return the product in a search result - Not working

Tags: soql, filters, search, parameters

I have a search page with a search box which returns a product (Sku) based on the product name the user enters or the description of the product itself.

With present code, the product is only returned if the product has been assigned a country. If there is no country assigned to the product, the product does not get returned in the search results. The requirement is for the product to be returned if EITHER customer OR area is assigned. I had a look at the code for this and could not figure out why it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I should be looking for/why this code is not working as required?

This is a snippet where the search result is returned and parameters are created:

```
public String getFilters()
{ 
        // Add parameters
        List<String> parameters = new List<String>();
        parameters.add('STATUS__c = \'Approved to order\'');
        parameters.add('Id IN (SELECT Variant_SKU__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Account__c = \'' + opp.AccountId + '\')');
        if(opp.Account.Country__c != null)
            parameters.add('Id IN (SELECT Variant_SKU__c FROM Geo__c WHERE Country__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__c + '\' ' + 
                       //'OR Country__r.Region__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__c + '\' ' + 
                       //'OR Country__r.Sub_Region__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__c + '\' ' + 
                       'OR Country__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__r.Region__c + '\' ' + 
                       'OR Country__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__r.Sub_Region__c + '\')');

        if (productName != null && productName != '')
            parameters.add('(Name LIKE \'%' + productName + '%\' OR SKU_Description__c LIKE \'%' + productName + '%\')');

        // Return filters
        if (!parameters.isEmpty())
            return ' WHERE ' + String.join(parameters, ' AND ');
        return '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another if statement and changed the existing if statement to an else if. It now looks like this and works as necessary:

```
public String getFilters() {
    // Add parameters
    List<String> parameters = new List<String>();
    parameters.add('STATUS__c = \'Approved to order\'');
    if(opp.AccountId != null)
        parameters.add('Id IN (SELECT Variant_SKU__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Account__c = \'' + opp.AccountId + '\')');
    else if(opp.Account.Country__c != null)
        parameters.add('Id IN (SELECT Variant_SKU__c FROM Geo__c WHERE Country__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__c + '\' ' + 
                   //'OR Country__r.Region__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__c + '\' ' + 
                   //'OR Country__r.Sub_Region__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__c + '\' ' + 
                   'OR Country__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__r.Region__c + '\' ' + 
                   'OR Country__c = \'' + opp.Account.Country__r.Sub_Region__c + '\')');

    if (productName != null && productName != '')
        parameters.add('(Name LIKE \'%' + productName + '%\' OR SKU_Description__c LIKE \'%' + productName + '%\')');

    // Return filters
    if (!parameters.isEmpty())
        return ' WHERE ' + String.join(parameters, ' AND ');
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
parameters.add('Id IN (SELECT Variant_SKU__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Account__c = \'' + opp.AccountId + '\')');
```

Is always applied, and concatenated to the area condition with `' AND '`.

Therefore the query will effectively be (pseudocode):

`WHERE other condition AND Account condition AND Country Condition AND other condition`

Hence, when the area is assigned but the customer is not, the record will not be returned.

You want to return the record if the area is assigned OR the customer is.  You can do this by rewriting the code to make the customer clause conditional, or by enclosing both clauses in brackets and separating them with an OR condition rather than an AND.  Pseudocode:

`WHERE other condition AND (Account condition OR Country Condition) AND other condition`

Comment: That didn't work for me. I tried many variations but in the end all I needed was an if else statement. Thanks for your time and help though!

Comment: I've removed the buggy code example to avoid confusing future viewers and just left the part explaining the problem and solution.